# My rotation driver variable loses a value greater than 180 degrees

Tags: drivers

[image]

I am trying to use the axis of rotation of a bone in a driver variable.
By the way, there is a problem when the rotation value is greater than 180 degrees.

For example, the transform displays -207, but the driver variable value displays 153.
I want to use -207, not 153.
I tried different Euler axes and quaternion as rotation options, but it didn't work.

How can I use a value greater than 180 degrees in the driver?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98711/why-does-copy-rotation-modifier-invert-after-180-degrees/98718#98718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Auto Euler** works the way I want.
It supports rotation values greater than 180.
Quaternion or other Euler options work with a 180 degree limit.
Depending on the situation, you may be able to use Auto Euler or other axis options.