# Linking two objects' rotations with relation to an factor?

Tags: keyframes

I really hope this question hasn't been asked before but I have looked and I can't find anything that helps me. Maybe I just don't know how to phrase it.

Anyways, the thing is: I have created an animation with lots of gears. And I want to let them rotate in the right speed. You see if Gear 1 rotates 360° in 10 seconds, than my smaller gear (2) must rotate faster than that. Say 720° in 10 seconds. Of course I can just put keyframes on every single gear but everytime that I change it, I have to change everything.

Is there a way to link the rotation of the other objects to my first object but in relation to an factor, for example f=0.5 so that object 2 rotates at half the speed that object 1 does?

Thanks in advance
MK

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98711/why-does-copy-rotation-modifier-invert-after-180-degrees/98718#98718

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience in them but this seems like something animation nodes would be an apt fit for.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you very much!