# Driver to rotate an object by y degrees every x frames?

Tags: python, animation, drivers

I am currently working on a wristwatch in Blender and want the second hand to tick 10 times every second, which using 30 fps would be every 3 frames.

Since one second is 6 degrees on a watch face, each of these rotations would have to rotate the second hand by `0.6` degrees. I know I somehow have to  use frame `% 3 == 0` for this, but cannot figure out how since I dont know Python.

Comment: radians(floor(frame/3)*0.6)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98711/why-does-copy-rotation-constraint-invert-after-180-degrees/98718#98718

Comment: Thank you very much @Nathan, works like a charm. Also applied it to the minute and hour hand with the same principle.