# Folding out shield for games and animations

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, game-engine

First of all, I'm new to 3d modeling.

I'm thinking of making a shield that can expand its size by folding out metallic plates around it like an umbrella, similar to the "loaded umbrella" from Sekiro.

Here's a quick sample animation I made that shows what I need to do [sample animation](https://youtu.be/WIseHiYQe7M)

[image]

I used an array modifier to make this but the problem is, when exporting it, I need to apply modifiers but then the animation no longer works because I used an object offset on an empty to animate this.
At first, I thought about using a bunch of bones with constraints but I can't find a way to do that.

So is there a way to make a shield like this, and make it so I can export this as an fbx or dae (I'm uploading this for others to buy) so anyone can download this and use it on games and animation?

Comment: In Blender, you can do such an animation with an Armature object and Bone Constraints (Copy Transformation, e.g. X-move => X-Rot) or an Action bone constraint. But I don't know if this works for exports and games.

Comment: Well, you probably have to bake an action (animation). This should be exportable.

Comment: @Blunder As long as I can export with animations (bake it) then it should be fine. I tried to use constraints. What I tried to do was make a main center bone and a bunch of other bones to the left. Then use constraints to restrict them from moving after a certain distance. But when I parent them to the main bone at the center, I couldn't get any location and rotation values for them because even though the bones do move, all the values are set to 0.

Comment: @Blunder when I try to bake the animation for the sample video above, since the animation is actually on an empty object, it just bake it's animation. And the array gets applied so I was left with just a bunch of objects jammed in one place with no animation.

Comment: I mean use an armature and then bake the animation to get rid of the bone constraints. Let me check where I put the example that I made ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creating the Animation**

The animation can be created by a rig. The *Armature* object in this example has 14 bones in total. A *Root* bone, a dozen of deformation bones, and a control bone for the rotation.

The green bones are the deformation bones with a *Transformation* bone constraint. When the control bone is rotated the deformation bones will do their rotation.

For the animation, only the root bones and the control bone have a few keyframes.
The "zoom in" effect at the beginning was done by scaling the root bone from 0.1 to 1.0.

[image: example animation]

The shield parts are parented directly to the deformation bones in this example. For exporting the animation into a game engine it might be better to use vertex groups and "weight paint" because parenting the mesh to a bone directly might not work. Make sure the root bone and the control bone have *not* ticked the `[_]` *Deform* option in the *Bone Properties* panel, and there are no vertex groups for them.

**Bone Constraints**

The *Map To > Max* value of the *Tranformation* bone constraints increases for each deformation bone (0° for the 1st, 30° for the 2nd, 60° for the 3rd, ..., 270° for the 10th, ..., and 330° for the 12th bone).

It's recommended to keyframe the rotation of the control bone first, so you can scrub the timeline and check the animation.

[image: bone constraints]

In the example, the control bone is rotated only from 0° to 179° because there is a limitation. But the deformation bones will do a rotation up to 360° because of the mapping. If you try to rotate the control bone more than 180° there will be a "flip" and the deformation bones will rotate the other way around (shortest rotation path). See [Why does copy rotation constraint invert after 180 degrees](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/98711/107598) for the details.

**Baking the Animation**

When you're happy with the animation you can make a backup and then bake the animation. The baking will remove the bone constraints and create keyframes for the deformation bones.

In *Pose* mode, select the menu entry *Pose > Animation > Bake Action...* and check `[X]` *Visual Keying* to bake the final transformations with the constraints applied, and check `[X]` *Clear Constraints* to remove them.

[image: Bake options]

Finally, you have the deformation bones with a lot of baked keyframes and without the bone constraints. You can delete the control bone. The baked action can be exported for game engines.

[image: baked action]

Comment: Man thank you. I was trying to parent them and use limit rotation. And then I tried using drivers, which actually works but a lot of work. This is way way better and exactly what I needed. Just a quick clarification, I need to parent ALL the bones to the root bone right?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, the root bone is there to easily move, rotate and scale the shield. It is the parent for all other bones.